# Select Box width without options

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am setting select box default width using the style:

```
.SelectListBox {
    background-color : #EBEBFF;
    width            : "200px";
}
```

I'm dynamically shifting elements from the select box to another using a right and left button. Initially my right select box is without options so in some browsers it is showing with zero width, but i want it to be `200px`, and i don't want to add any blank options as my server side code is dependent on it.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s7sbd/)

Comment: What, precisely, is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the line  **width:"200px";**

It should be

```
 width:200px;
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s7sbd/2/)

Answer (score 3):

`width:"200px";` isn't valid, use `width: 200px;`

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s7sbd/3/)

Answer (score 1):

It's just `width: 200px;` not `width:"200px";`

Answer (score 1):

use `width:200px` instead of `width:"200px"` (it is not valid code).

Fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/s7sbd/5/

Answer (score 1):

Aside from invalid syntax, you can use `min-width` as well just in case. To cater longer text greater than `200px`

```
.SelectListBox
{
    background-color:#EBEBFF;
    min-width:200px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s7sbd/7/)